# How to filter data and alter cell index

Tags: excel

Initally, cell **C9=A2**. (See the left situation of image 1).

[image]

Next, when I filter the data and exclude "Team A", for instance, (see the right situation of [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mELLu.png)), I want **C9** to show **the next top value under A1**.

In this case, that would mean **C9** needs to show the value of **A5**. Is there a formula I can use for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will **Player** always be numeric and sorted in order as you show?

Comment: Yes, "player" will remain sorted in numerical order.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data is in A1 to B19 and you want the first cell of column A in cell c9 after filtered the column A
here is the formula

```
=INDEX(A2:A19,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A19)-ROW(A2),0)),ROW(A2:A19)-ROW(A2)+1)))
Select c9 and copy the formula into formula bar and hit ctrl+shift+enter (since its array formula) it will select the first value of column A after applying filter.
```

Note: you may adjust the column A data range, for example, I have selected A2 to A19
[image: FIlter-Team A]
[image: Filter-Team B]

Comment: =INDEX(A2:A19,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A19)-ROW(A2),0)),ROW(A2:A19)-ROW(A2)+1))) shows the value of A2, after column B is filtered there's an error. It does work with sorting, but not with filtering. (I have edited the query to make it more accurate.)

Answer (score 0):

I used a Table with Structured References because

- I think it makes the formula easier to understand
- the references are not dependent on the position of the table in the worksheet
- and the references will auto adjust as you add/subtract rows.

After clarification from the OP, it seems that PLayers will always be numeric and sorted ascending.  That being the case, you merely use

```
=SUBTOTAL(5,Table1[Player])
```

**EDIT**:  In response to the change in your question, where you are, apparently, now looking for a formula that will return sequential visible rows

Try:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,5,Table1[Player],ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

The `5` option argument is to ignore hidden rows.

**Unfiltered**

[image]

**Filter A only**

[image]

**Filter B only**

[image]

Comment: =INDEX(A2:A500,SUBTOTAL(5,A2:A500),1) works except in one situation: when I filter out Team A and show Team B I get the desired result "4, 5, 6" in the C column; however, when I filter out Team B and just show Team A the results are "1, 3, 5" everytime... whereas the results should be "1, 2, 3". Any idea what could be the cause of that error?

Comment: @Etsenmaker  I've edited my post now that I better understand your question.  But how (and why) are you returning a comma-separated string?  My formula will always return the topmost cell in the Players column.

Comment: @RonRosenfield, in that case, what would be the code for displaying the data in the second and third cell from the top?

Comment: @Etsenmaker That is a very different question form your first question, but I will edit my answer.  On this forum, it is best if you initially ask a question about your real problem, rather than asking for a solution to a problem that you assume will be adaptable to your real problem. Take a look at [What is the XY  problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Etsenmaker See the edited question which will return sequential values of the visible rows only.  That should be what you want.